# Try  в try определение ошибки

Tags: c#

Какой MessageBox выполнится?

```
 try{
    try{
    //Тут код с ошибкой
    }
    catch{
    MessageBox.Show('1-вый блок');
    }
    }
    catch{
    MessageBox.Show('2-рой блок');
    }
```

Comment: вам лень проверить самому?

Comment: MessageBox.Show('1-вый блок');
Но только не скомпилится))
т.к. нужно использовать двойные кавычки "

Comment: Да, мне лень. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Выполнится первый](https://ideone.com/jJPjum)